# How and where to draw JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I am writing a little application in which i want a gui that splits a window into two sections, each of which will be controlled by a JPanel. I want to add an input field and a set of buttons on the left side. I have the code:

```
public ModalModeller() {
    super("Modal Modeller"); 
    //setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setSize(1000, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    font = new Font("Sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    setUpTextInputField();
    setUpButtons();
    setUpPanels();
    setVisible(true);
}
public void setUpTextInputField() {
    inputField = new JTextField(30);
    inputField.addActionListener( // anonymous inner class
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String s = inputField.getText();
                    ExprStr inputExpression = new ExprStr(s);
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            });
    //add(inputField);
}
public void setUpButtons() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints buttonConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    buttonConstraints.gridx = 0;
    buttonConstraints.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    buttonConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

    reflexB = new JRadioButton();
    reflexB.addActionListener(this);
    reflexB.setFont(font);

    transB = new JRadioButton();
    transB.addActionListener(this);
    transB.setFont(font);

    symmB = new JRadioButton();
    symmB.addActionListener(this);
    symmB.setFont(font);

    hereditaryB = new JRadioButton();
    hereditaryB.addActionListener(this);
    hereditaryB.setFont(font);

    buttonPanel.add(reflexB);
    buttonPanel.add(transB);
    buttonPanel.add(symmB);
    buttonPanel.add(hereditaryB);


}
public void setUpPanels() {
    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    rightPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.black);


    GridBagConstraints leftConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints rightConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    leftConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    leftConstraints.gridx = 0;
    leftConstraints.gridy = 0;
    leftPanel.add(inputField, leftConstraints);

    leftConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    leftConstraints.gridx = 1;
    leftConstraints.gridy = 0;
    leftPanel.add(buttonPanel, leftConstraints);
    add(leftPanel);
    add(rightPanel);
}
```

I know that the inputTextField works when I don't draw it within a JPanel, but for some reason neither of the JPanels is being drawn in my window. Why is this? Have I added them in the wrong place? Is it something wrong with the layout I have selected?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you consider using a `JSplitPane`?

Comment: Since you're breaking your code down into components, which is good, I would consider making them into custom components, it will simplify your code and make it easier to maintain

Comment: buttonPanel is a variable that is local to the method setUpButtons(). Since you do not add that panel to anything, when that method ends the buttonPanel and all of its contents are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a litany of issues...

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, you never seem to change it, this means that when you add `leftPanel` and then `rightPanel`, it's right panel which is winning and been displayed.

Next, the reason you're not seeing anything on the `rightPanel` is because you're not actually adding anything to it

```
leftConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
leftConstraints.gridx = 0;
leftConstraints.gridy = 0;
leftPanel.add(inputField, leftConstraints);

leftConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
leftConstraints.gridx = 1;
leftConstraints.gridy = 0;
leftPanel.add(buttonPanel, leftConstraints);
```

Both these blocks add components to the `leftPanel`.

What I think you want to do, in the second block, is something more like...

```
rightConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
rightConstraints.gridx = 1;
rightConstraints.gridy = 0;
rightPanel.add(buttonPanel, leftConstraints);
```

Once I correct for all those issues, your code works

## Runnable Example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ModalModeller extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ModalModeller();
  }

  private JTextField inputField;
  private JPanel buttonPanel;
  private JRadioButton reflexB;
  private JRadioButton transB;
  private JRadioButton symmB;
  private JRadioButton hereditaryB;
  private JPanel leftPanel;
  private JPanel rightPanel;

  public ModalModeller() {
    super("Modal Modeller");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    setSize(1000, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUpTextInputField();
    setUpButtons();
    setUpPanels();

    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void setUpTextInputField() {
    inputField = new JTextField(30);
    inputField.addActionListener( // anonymous inner class
            new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = inputField.getText();
//      ExprStr inputExpression = new ExprStr(s);
        System.out.println(s);
      }
    });
    //add(inputField);
  }

  public void setUpButtons() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints buttonConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    buttonConstraints.gridx = 0;
    buttonConstraints.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    buttonConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

    reflexB = new JRadioButton();
//  reflexB.addActionListener(this);

    transB = new JRadioButton();
//  transB.addActionListener(this);

    symmB = new JRadioButton();
//  symmB.addActionListener(this);

    hereditaryB = new JRadioButton();
//  hereditaryB.addActionListener(this);

    buttonPanel.add(reflexB);
    buttonPanel.add(transB);
    buttonPanel.add(symmB);
    buttonPanel.add(hereditaryB);

  }

  public void setUpPanels() {
    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    rightPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.black);

    GridBagConstraints leftConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints rightConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    leftConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    leftConstraints.gridx = 0;
    leftConstraints.gridy = 0;
    leftPanel.add(inputField, leftConstraints);

    rightConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    rightConstraints.gridx = 1;
    rightConstraints.gridy = 0;
    rightPanel.add(buttonPanel, leftConstraints);
    add(leftPanel);
    add(rightPanel);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but for some reason neither of the JPanels is being drawn in my window

Not sure why they both don't display, but I know why the left panel doesn't display.

From what I can tell you are using a JFrame. The default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. You attempt to add the two panels to the frame using:

```
add(leftPanel);
add(rightPanel);
```

However, when you add components to a BorderLayout and don't specify a constraint, then the component is added to the CENTER. However, only one component can be added to the CENTER so the BorderLayout only manages the last component added.

> i want a gui that splits a window into two sections

So instead of structuring your code based on all the panel you are creating, I would structure the code based on the panels you want to add to the frame.

So the code in your constructor would be something like:

```
add(createLeftPane(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
add(createCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

So now at a high level you know you add two main panels to the frame.

Then the code might be something like:

```
private JPanel createLeftPanel()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add( new JButton("Left Panel Button") );
    return panel;
}
```

You would add similar code for the `createCenterPanel()` method.

Then once you have the two top level panel displaying, you can add your real component to each panel using whatever layout manager you want to use.

Form design should be an iterative approach.